# java method returning an instance of Class<T extends Somethng>

Tags: java, generics, java-7

i've got this code:

```java
public <T extends Scrapper> Class<T> getScrapper() {
    return MyScrapper.class;
}
```

`MyScrapper` is a class implementing `Scrapper` interface. Why is this not working? U'm getting the following error in JDK7:

```
error: incompatible types
required: Class<T>
found:    Class<MyScrapper>
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Scrapper declared in method <T>getScrapper()
```

P.S.
I've honestly tried searching for whole 30-40 minutes.

Update:
if i declare the method as `public Class<? extends Scrapper> getScrapper() {` it works. but I still don't understand why the original declaration was not compiling. what's wrong with it?

Comment: What happens if you just set <T extends Scrapper> to <Scrapper>

Comment: the way you suggest it should not work imo. but i tried something else and it worked. I updated the question

Comment: Yeah I'm getting tired. I meant change just to Scrapper (unparameterized) but you got it to work using a class argument and if that fits your purposes right on

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a generic method like `getScrapper()`, the *caller* of the method determines what the actual type argument to the method is (`T` in this case). The caller could pick any subtype of `Scrapper` as `T`, and your method (which always returns `MyScrapper.class`) would not be returning the correct class.

Given the signature of the method, the caller of this method would expect to be able to do this:

```
Class<MyOtherScrapper> c = foo.<MyOtherScrapper>getScrapper();
```

Changing the method to return `Class<? extends Scrapper>` makes it no longer a generic method... there are no type parameters for the caller to set. Instead, the signature says that the method returns the class object for *some unknown subtype* of `Scrapper`, and `MyScrapper.class` does fit the bill for that.

Comment: Thank you :) looks like I was tired and dumb yesterday when i asked this question :D Should have got it myself :)